# Blank page on login/logout with history.push in React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, react-router-dom, use-effect

Having a problem when I login and when I logout with React Router Dom.
When I click login, it correctly set the cookie but the address does not update. So, I need to update manually the address to make it work.
When I click logout, it correctly delete the cookie and correctly updates the address but it shows me a blank page. So I need to refresh the page to make it work.
What am I doing wrong?

Here's a slice of my code:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Route, Switch, useHistory,
} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  const jwt = Cookies.get(StringsConst.jwt);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (jwt) {
      const loggedUser = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
      if (loggedUser) {
        history.push(PathConst.toHomePage);
      } else {
        history.push(PathConst.toLoginPage);
      }
    }
  }, [jwt]);
 
  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={PathConst.toLoginPage} exact>
          {jwt ? history.push(PathConst.toRootPage) : <Login />}
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={PathConst.toHomePage}>
          {jwt ? <Dashboard /> : history.push(PathConst.toLoginPage) }
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}
```

**EDIT still not working**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Route, Switch, useHistory, Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  const jwt = Cookies.get(StringsConst.jwt);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (jwt) {
      const loggedUser = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
      if (loggedUser) {
        history.push(PathConst.toHomePage);
      } else {
        history.push(PathConst.toLoginPage);
      }
    }
  }, [jwt]);

  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={PathConst.toLoginPage} exact>
           {jwt ? <Redirect to={PathConst.toHomePage} /> : <Login />}
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={PathConst.toHomePage}>
           {jwt ? <Dashboard /> : <Redirect to={PathConst.toLoginPage} /> }
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}
```

It doesn't change the path at all after I click on login submit button. It goes in the useEffect and in the return just once at the very begininning. It does not care about the dependencies in the useEffect

Comment: Could you setup a minimal reproducable example on CodeSandbox for example? It's way easier to check what is wrong than just reading code here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A possibility of the useEffect not retriggering is because your `jwt` value is not a state, if the component does not rerender your jwt value will not be recalculated either

Answer (score 0):

The children of Route needs to be a component . history.push(...) is responsible just to update the route . It does not render a component . Replace history.push() with `Redirect` from `react-router-dom`

```
<Switch>
        <Route path={PathConst.toLoginPage} exact>
          {jwt ? <Redirect to={PathConst.toRootPage)/> : <Login />}
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={PathConst.toHomePage}>
          {jwt ? <Dashboard /> : <Redirect to={PathConst.toLoginPage) /> }
        </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post with your solution, but it's not working yet. What am I doing wrong

Comment: I think I will manage it just making it read the value of jwt every time it changes, which is not happening now